# Coercion of numeric columns with decimals and points

Tags: r, coercion

I would like to know how do I turn values into numerics, since they involve decimals and points. Thank you for your help.

```
c("1.139,0000", "1.160,0000", "1.160,0000", "1.160,0000", "1.160,0000", 
"1.194,0000", "1.533,3500", "1.550,0000", "1.550,0000", "1.602,0000", 
"1.825,0000", "1.825,0000", "1.825,0000", "1.825,0000", "1.825,0000", 
"1.825,0000", "1.825,0000", "1.825,4000", "1.825,0000", "1.825,0000", 
"2.042,1234", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", 
"2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", 
"2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000", "2.200,0000"
)
```

Desired output:

```
c("1139.0000", "1160.0000", "1160.0000", "1160.0000", "1160.0000", 
    "1194.0000", "1533.3500", "1550.0000", "1550.0000", "1602.0000", 
    "1825.0000", "1825.0000", "1825.0000", "1825.0000", "1825.0000", 
    "1825.0000", "1825.0000", "1825.4000", "1825.0000", "1825.0000", 
    "2042.1234", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", 
    "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", 
    "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000", "2200.0000"
    )
```

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub(',|\\.', '', x))`

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, it didn't work the way I expected.

Comment: Well observed @Ronak Shah, I put the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you can use `sub` to remove `.` and replace `,` with `.`.

```
as.numeric(sub(',', '.', sub('.', '', x, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE))

# [1] 1139.000 1160.000 1160.000 1160.000 1160.000 1194.000 1533.350 1550.000
# [9] 1550.000 1602.000 1825.000 1825.000 1825.000 1825.000 1825.000 1825.000
#[17] 1825.000 1825.400 1825.000 1825.000 2042.123 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000
#[25] 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000
#[33] 2200.000 2200.000 2200.000
```

We can also use `parse_number` from `readr` specifying `decimal_mark` as comma.

```
library(readr)
parse_number(x, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ','))
```

Comment: Very grateful @Ronak Shah, what is the meaning of `fixed = TRUE` ?

Comment: Function like `sub`/`gsub`/`grep`/`grepl` use regular expressions to match/extract text. `.` has a special meaning in regex but here we want to match a literal `.` in the text so we include `fixed = TRUE` so that it exactly matches a `.`.